# In order to soundproof the noise from outside, how to install studwork on concrete walls and ceiling? How to fix stud on the walls and ceiling?

Tags: sound-proofing

This [video](https://youtu.be/hJlz1L_cYgU?t=21) demonstrate how to build a stud wall.

My room looks like the following image, concrete walls and ceiling

[image]

In order to soundproof the noise from outside, how to install studwork on concrete walls and ceiling?

How to fix stud on the walls and ceiling?

Comment: I haven't watched the video, but you'll have a better chance of getting a good answer if you ask a very specific question, for example, "The video said to do 'x'. I'm not sure how to do 'x' because my situation is different from that in the video because of 'y'"

Comment: Although I did upvote, the question was how to secure the top plate to concrete. But your advice would probably have gotten an answer much faster.

Answer (score -1):

A concrete wall having outside noise issues? Hummm I do think I have heard of that problem. 
If you want to isolate the wall from the living space that may work but will make the room smaller.

To anchor into concrete you will usually need to drill the plate and extend the hole into the concrete and use a tapcon or concrete screw. There are other methods but many are not easily removed and you may not be happy with the results and want to reclaim the space.

Comment: And you'll need an SDS drill to make holes in concrete. An ordinary hammer drill (especially a cordless drill) will takes ages, if it manages it at all.

Comment: @Robin Bennett I use a dewalt 20v 1/2” all the time for small anchors like Tapcon screws and 1/4” expanding anchors all the time. Larger sizes I agree and have a Hilti for larger holes but for smaller holes a hammer drill combo works ok.

Comment: Except that a sound-proof wall shouldn't be rigidly connected to the concrete. It needs isoliation.

Comment: I did not say to connect it to the wall I said to isolate to me means not in contact and answered how to anchor in concrete.